# Comparison of hashable objects

Tags: python, hash, set

I have a tuple of python objects, from which I need a list of objects with no duplicates, using `set()` (this check for duplicate objects is to be done on an attribute.). This code will give a simple illustration:

```
class  test:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.t)
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.t
l = (test(1), test(2), test(-1), test(1), test(3), test(2))
print l
print set(l)
```

However, it did not work. I can do it on an iteration over `l`, but any idea why `set()` is not working? [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is the official documentation.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but avoid using `l` as an identifier in any language because it looks too much like `1`. In Python, the next strongest temptation is to use the name `list` which is even worse as you'll see if you try to execute `list = list([])` twice.

Comment: @msw: Is `1` vs `l` _really_ a problem? Good fonts or syntax highlighting make that a complete non-issue

Comment: And poor fonts, lack of syntax highlighting, reader fatigue, and many other factors make it an issue except under the optimal circumstances you have at your disposal. Is discouraging known bad practice _really_ a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to:

> The set classes are implemented using dictionaries. Accordingly, the
>   requirements for set elements are the same as those for dictionary
>   keys; namely, that the element defines **both `__eq__()` and `__hash__()`**.

To be more specific, if `a == b` then your implementation must be such that `hash(a) == hash(b)`. The reverse is not required.

Also, you should probably call `hash` in `__hash__` to handle long integers

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.t)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.t)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Test) and self.t == other.t
```

Comment: @msw: Because renaming the author's variables in an answer is confusing, and in this case, misleading

Answer (score 1):

Small nit picks:
Your implementation of `__eq__` doesn't give the other object a chance to run its own `__eq__`. The class must also consider its members as immutable as the hash must stay constant. You don't want to break your dicts, do you?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self._t = t

    @property
    def t(self):
        return self._t

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._t)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._t)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Test):
            return NotImplemented # don't know how to handle `other`
        return self.t == other.t
```